# Combining Ant and Maven projects

Tags: java, maven, ant

I'm working in very big java project, consisting of many smaller maven modules and one web module which is maintained using ant. Now, I need to access in my web module projects written in maven modules. Is it possible to somehow add maven modules to ant project?

I have tried to make jar files from maven modules and simple add them to ant project, but I received errors `ClassNotFoundException` and `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Answer (score 2):

You can integrate maven dependencies with Apache Ant by using [Maven Ant Tasks](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use a Maven repository manager like Nexus, Artifactory or Archiva to store jars built by your Maven project.

The [Apache ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) plugin for ANT can then be used to pull these as dependencies (Ivy can also be used to store jars in a Maven repo but that is another question).

## Example

```
├── build.xml
├── ivysettings.xml
└── target
    └── WEB-INF
        └── lib
            ├── log4j-1.2.17.jar
            ├── slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
            └── slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="resolve" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

  <property name="build.dir" location="target"/>

  <available classname="org.apache.ivy.Main" property="ivy.installed"/>

  <target name="resolve" depends="install-ivy" description="Use ivy to resolve classpaths">
    <ivy:retrieve pattern="${build.dir}/WEB-INF/lib/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]">
      <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-api" rev="1.7.5" conf="default"/>
      <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-log4j12" rev="1.7.5" conf="default"/>
    </ivy:retrieve>
  </target>

  <target name="install-ivy" unless="ivy.installed">
    <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
    <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/ivy.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.4.0/ivy-2.4.0.jar"/>
    <fail message="Ivy installed  run build again"/>
  </target>

  <target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="clean-all" depends="clean">
    <ivy:cleancache/>
  </target>

</project>
```

Notes:

- The "install-ivy" target is optional and my recommended way to ensure the ivy plugin jar is installed on your build server
- The ivy [retrieve](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/retrieve.html) task is used to resolve dependencies and place them within the project space
- The ivy [cleancache](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/cleancache.html) task purges the local ivy cache.

### ivysettings.xml

```
<ivysettings>
  <settings defaultResolver="my-resolvers"/>
  <resolvers>
    <chain name="my-resolvers" returnFirst="true">
      <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true"/>
      <ibiblio name="myrepo" root="http://mavenrepo/path/to/repo" m2compatible="true"/>
    </chain>
  </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

Note:

- The ivy configuration file is optional and this example demonstrates how both [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/) and a local Maven repository can be used as a source of dependencies.